# How to kill known running pids if one of the pids terminated?

Tags: bash, kill

I have this script.sh where I pass the path to the binaries, all apps run in the background:

```
./script.sh path/to/app_1 path/to/app_2 ... path/to/app_n
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for app in "$@"
do
    $app &
done
```

All my apps are running as I expected. Some of them are just console applications without windows, but some apps have interface and I can close the window app.

I can get pid of the app, something like this:

```
pgrep "${app##*/}"
```

How to kill all apps by pids that I passed through script.bash as arguments? When I close one of the windows it should kill all known running apps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One suggestion, assuming the amount of processes being started is static, is to add every pid to an array, and possibly increment a variable that counts what length you expect that array to be. You could then run a `while true` infinite loop that either checks if the values are different, or if the pid array length is lower than expected (whichever works best), and when that is no longer true you send `kill` to every pid in the array and exit the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
declare -a _procid

_kill_them_all()
{
    for p in ${_procid[@]} ; do
        kill -9 $p 2>/dev/null
    done
    exit
}

trap _kill_them_all SIGCHLD

for app in "$@"
do
    $app  &
    _procid+=($!)
done

wait ${_procid[@]}

echo "doesn't get here if there were children"
```

The bash script keeps an array list of the child pids, and traps when any of the child processes exit, then the trap handler kills all the child processes.

Comment: Why do you use `SIGKILL` (`-9`)? Wouldn't be nice to use `kill` without any option (sending `SIGTERM`)?  Also, you have a whole bunch of unquoted variables in your code.

Comment: @stevea, thanks, that's what i needed

Comment: It doesn't work on Mac, but works on Linux. Another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621260/12797579